# Clear /trace Spring Boot actuator endpoint

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to clear out the contents of the `/trace` actuator endpoint in Spring Boot? It would be much easier to debug without wading through a ton of previous calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, Spring Boot uses an instance of `InMemoryTraceRepository` to store all of the trace events. This `TraceRepository` implementation doesn't provide a mechanism to clear all of its events, but does limit the number of events to, by default, 100.

You can replace `InMemoryTraceRepository` with your own `@Bean` that implements `TraceRepository`. You're then free to implement any mechanism of your choosing to clear out the repository. One obvious way to do this would be to sub-class `InMemoryTraceRepository`, however its design doesn't lend itself to subclassing at the moment. If you'd like this to change, or if you'd like Spring Boot to provide its own mechanism for clearing the repository, please [open an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/new).

Comment: Do you know how can I store all trace events using TraceRepository?
If I would create @Bean that implements TraceRepository, how can I catch events and store them?